# How to Rollback the ngModel two Way binding data in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I have a form in angular 2 with two way binding data value ([(ngModel)]) for edit and add functionality.

User clicks the edit from the listing page and changes the value in the input , while editing the changed(new) values appear in the list page also, instead of the save clicks cancel button. Need to display the old value in listing page.

```
project-form.component.html
---------------------------
   <input class="form-control"  type="text" size="30" pInputText [(ngModel)]="project.title" name="title" pTooltip="Enter your username"/>

    <ul class="list-group">
          <li *ngFor="let event of project" class="list-group-item">
            <span class="event_release">{{event.startDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </span><br />
            <strong>{{event.title}}</strong>
          </li>
        </ul>

Project-form.component.ts 
-------------------------
@Input() project: Project;
```

While submitting sending the variable  (this.project) holds updated values (tow way binding variable), need to be roll-backed if the user click the cancel button (this.project).

Comment: add some code snippet or code link

Answer (score 0):

just create a deep copy of `project` object. the problem you are facing is due the fact that list page and edit page is working on same copy of the object so change the object at one place will be reflected in other place also.

### use this javascript code(do this in edit page)

`let project_copy =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(project))`

and then in edit instead of working on project variable work with this project_copy